# When I run my test case, my main method of spring-boot gets evoked and my mockito method doesn't work. How to solve this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have written a test case which mocks a method call by which the application is reading an excel file from the system. When I run my test case in debug, I observe that my control goes through the main method of my spring-boot application and instead of getting the mocked value in my service method, I get only null. As a result, I'm getting a null pointer exception in the very next line.

I am not sure as to how to properly run the application in a test mode where I can successfully mock the method call that I'm trying to.

Test method:

```
@Test
    public void testReadQuery() throws IOException {
        QueryReader mockQueryReader = Mockito.mock(QueryReader.class);
        Mockito.when(fileReaderWriter.readFile())
          .thenReturn(mockDataRetriever.getResponseObject(new File(getClass().getResource(TestConstants.TEST_QUERY).getFile())));
        Object mockTableObj = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(mockQueryReader, "tableObj");
        ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(mockQueryReader, "readQuery");
        assertNotNull(mockTableObj);
    }
```

Main method class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QueryBuilderApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        queryReader.readQuery();

        exit(0);
    }
```

Service method:

```
public void readQuery() {

        try {

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = fileReaderWriter.readFile();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            String sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.QueryBuilder.reader.QueryReader.readQuery(QueryReader.java:31)
    at com.QueryBuilder.QueryBuilderApplication.run(QueryBuilderApplication.java:25)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this occurs because you don't stub all object in the class that you want to test. For the default, Mockito returns you the default values on the stubbed methods of the mock object, such as Null for an object and false for a Boolean.

To verify my opinion, you can use, to create the mock instances, the below statements

```
Mockito.mock(ClassToTest.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

that it returns you a deep stub. For example:

```java
@Test
public void when_returns_deep_stub() throws Exception {
    ClassToTest classToTestWithDeepStub = Mockito.mock(ClassToTest.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    // the object1 and object2 mock is not defined
    // deep call of getString method
    when(classToTestWithDeepStub.getObject1().getObject2().getString())
    .thenReturn("Deep Stub");
    // a deep stubbed mock is returned
    System.out.println("classToTestWithDeepStub.getObject1().getObject2().getString()"
    + classToTestWithDeepStub.getObject1().getObject2().getString());
    assertNotNull(classToTestWithDeepStub.getObject1().getObject2().getString());
}
```

Console output

```
 classToTestWithDeepStub.getObject1().getObject2().getString()=Deep Stub.
```

---

**The second solution**

From your question, I understand that the fileReaderWriter is null, isn't it true? if this is true, I don't see the mock of the fileReaderWrite and the mock injection in the QueryReader class. Would you give me more details or statements of your implementations?
Else my advice is to follow the below way.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReadQueryTest {

  @Mock
  private FileReaderWriter fileReaderWriter;

  @Test
  public void testReadQuery() throws IOException { 
     QueryReader queryReader = new QueryReader(fileReaderWriter);
     when(fileReaderWriter.readFile())
          .thenReturn(mockDataRetriever.getResponseObject(new File(getClass().getResource(TestConstants.TEST_QUERY).getFile())));
     queryReader.readQuery();
     assertNotNull(queryReader.getTableObj());
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the same result. My primary problem is that in spite of using ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(), the method is not being called but instead the main method of spring-boot gets invoked as would happen on application start-up.

Comment: From the question, I understand that the fileReaderWriter is null, isn't it true? if this is true, I don't see the mock of fileReaderWrite and the injection of the mock in the QueryReader class. Would you give me more details or statements of your implementations? Above an example of my solution.

Comment: Yes, the snippet you provided seems helpful but the primary problem remains. I tried debugging my test method by providing a break-point at the very first line. When I debugged as a Junit test case, the control stopped at a break-point installed at the main method of my application instead of the test case. As a result, the mock injection is not working, leading to a null pointer exception.

Comment: If you use the MockitoJUnitRunner to run the test, the execution should not pass in the main method. What IDE do you use? How do you run the test case? I need more info.

Comment: MockitoJUnitRunner did the trick! I had been using the wrong runner (SpringRunner) all along. I can at least run the test case now, which I am going to implement properly. Will post an update once that's done too. Thank you so much for this help, you have been very kind and patient with me. :)

Comment: It is a pleasure :D the IT world is a jungle and a hand is always useful.

Comment: Excuse me, could you set the resolution as a correct response? Thank you.

Comment: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "testFileReaderWriter")
public class QueryBuilderApplicationTest {`

There you go.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to run my application with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as I found this is also a probable alternative. But this is what causing the main application class to run instead of the test case. Any idea why?

Comment: To test your class, you just need the unit test annotations, the @SpringBootTest annotations starts the application and initializes the spring context for the integration test.